# Linking 2 Linux Virtual Machines with a python socket and client script not working

Tags: python, linux, virtual-machine

I am trying to get a virtual machine to send a string/list to a second virtual machine and then have the second virtual machine return a string to the first virtual machine.
To do this, I have decided to go with a Python socket server and client script.
The virtual machines are both hosted via Oracle. Here is the code:

Server:

```
import socket

SERVER_IP = "localhost"
SERVER_PORT = 8000

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_socket.bind((SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT))

server_socket.listen(1)

print("Server listening on", SERVER_IP, "port", SERVER_PORT)

client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
print("Connection from:", client_address)

data = client_socket.recv(1024)
print("Received data:", data.decode())

response = "Hello from the server!"
client_socket.send(response.encode())

client_socket.close()
server_socket.close()
```

Client:

```
import socket

SERVER_IP = "(Server Public IP Address)"
SERVER_PORT = 8000

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

client_socket.connect((SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT))

data = "Hello from the client!"
client_socket.send(data.encode())

response = client_socket.recv(1024)
print("Response from server:", response.decode())

client_socket.close()
```

I have opened up the port 8000 (tcp) with this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Vgzvh2jqRQ

I have tried making the "localhost" with the actual public ip address
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

I have made both machines ping each other successfully.
using ping (public ip)

Additionally, I tried to allow all protocols, but then when i run the code,

```
OSError: [Errno 113] No route to host
```

When running the code, the code does not show any indication of connection.
(with specifying src:8000 dst:8000 ip protcol" tcp)
I have no idea what to do

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To do this

1. Install Tail Scale and set up
2. Keep the rule allowing TCP on port 8000 as the src, leaving all for dst. CIDR is 0.0.0.0/0
3. Run program using tail scale ip

Comment: The question is quite clearly pointing to a networking configuration issue within your Oracle Cloud instance. Setting up a VPN like Tailscale (or publicly routing this traffic outside Oracle's network to begin with) is completely unnecessary overhead and will incur way more cost than doing this the right way by verifying that either (a) both VMs exist within the same virtual cloud network or (b) the VCNs themselves are sufficiently [peered to one another](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Tasks/VCNpeering.htm).

Comment: I wanted to use public ips because I wanted to run the same program on other machines such as a google VM or maybe my own laptop. Tailscale was an easy solution for that compared to trying to understand Oracles VCNs and security lists etc. Sorry I forgot to clarify that